# Orchard CMS Error "ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, orchardcms

I I am using orchard 1.8.1 and try to install the theme Bootstrap and it gives me the following errors. Can anyone help me out?
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.

```
Line 61:         // Load the log4net thread with additional properties if they are available
Line 62:         protected internal void AddExtendedThreadInfo() {
Line 63:             if (_shellSettings.Value != null) {
Line 64:                 ThreadContext.Properties["Tenant"] = _shellSettings.Value.Name;
Line 65:             }
```

Comment: Guys, Let me know if you need any more details about the error get it fixed !! @Puneet Goel

Answer (score 1):

Just found that it seems to work if, in OrchardLog4netLogger.cs, we replace

```
_shellSettings = new Lazy<ShellSettings>(LoadSettings);
```

With

```
_shellSettings = new Lazy<ShellSettings>(LoadSettings,
     System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);
```

Then, all threads are allowed to run the initialization method. The first thread to complete initialization sets the value of the Lazy instance

Comment: +1, works for me. I posted link to your solution to the [official Orchard GIT's issue thread](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6350). If the Orchard developers won't find any reason against (like other issues triggered by your solution), they will likely add it to the next version of Orchard.

Comment: @PavelV, that would be great. Thanks for sharing.