# Error: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property

Tags: c#, android, .net, winforms, xamarin

When I try to launch the android emulator, I get this error in the output window. I dont know where this error is happening in the code to even troubleshoot it. Can i get some assistance? How to debug this?

Error: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.

Comment: any stack trace? similar problem :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161210/error-valuefactory-attempted-to-access-the-value-property-of-this-instance

Comment: In the post, I am not for what are they referencing as far as the app data. What is the app data and where is the app data

Comment: Hi, by `android emulator`, is it a VS emulator or Google Emulator?

Comment: same issue here, using official google emulator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidOperationException in my Lazy<> value factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300398/invalidoperationexception-in-my-lazy-value-factory)